# Broken gpg key from google kubernetes kubectl

Tags: kubectl, gpg-signature

So I'm trying to install kubectl from the official repository but I'm getting an error while adding their key: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg .

I've tried `user@machine:~/Downloads$ gpg --verify apt-key.gpg 
gpg: verify signatures failed: Unexpected error`

Is it a bad key for you also? I'm using a DeepinOS for the first time so perhaps it's some internal issue?

Comment: `gpg --verify` is used to verify the signature on a data file.  But `apt-key.gpg` isn't data with a signature; it's just a key, so it doesn't make sense to "verify" it.  The key itself seems fine.  What do you actually want to do with it?  If you want to add it to your apt keyring, use `apt-key add`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my corporate proxy was changing the file so the command `sudo apt-key add apt-key.gpg` was failing with 'Unexpected error'. The download site didn't hash to compare.